# Adding -classpath from command line

Tags: java, classpath

So I have two java files, Print.java and StaticImport.java, in src/com/test.

StaticImport.java:

```
package com.test;
import static com.test.*;

class StaticImport {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    Print.print("This is cool");
  }
}
```

Print.java:

```
package com.test;

public class Print {
  public static void Print(String command) {
    System.out.println(command);
  }
}
```

So basically there is the `StaticImport class` that uses `Print class`.
How can I compile the `StaticImport` with `javac` in command line?
I have tried for example: `javac -cp /home/pathToProj/ StaticImport.java`, but with no success.

Comment: You need to `import com.test.*;` or (and this is what you're going for, I think) `import static com.test.Print.*;`. This isn't what your question is about obviously, it's just something you'll need to change to get it working later :) If you use the static import, then you can replace `Print.print(...)` with `print(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, the classpath contains class files, not java code.

First, you need to compile Print.java, since you need it to be on your classpath. Then you need to set the classpath for the compilation of StaticImport to be the directory containing the "com" directory above Print.class.

You can also compile both files at the same time, using a single call to `javac`.

However, the best thing to do is to use either [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build it for you. They look after your classpath, and do a million other things besides.